# When I switch the mode default to developer of magento2.2.3 then got this error Element 'count': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, xml, developer-mode

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'count': This element is not expected. Expected is ( argument
>   ). Line: 1077

Comment: Whether is it a fresh instance. Php version please

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.30

Answer (score 0):

You have error in one of your xml files, where you have specified a 'count' node in wrong place. Please check one xml you've recently modified or search for xml for 'count' keyword.

Comment: this issue show only product list page...for this reason we replace magento catalog module from luma theme...but error is still showing...@Vivek Kumar

Comment: Then the error must be one of your catalog_product_view.xml